# Python Dictionary output

Tags: python, dictionary

I am hoping someone can explain this to me.

Given the following dictionary:

```
users = {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith', 'age': 27}
```

The following for loop:

```
for k in users:
    print(k, '=>', users[k])

firstname => John
lastname => Smith
age => 27
```

results in the same output as the one below:

```
for k, v in users.items():
    print(k, '=>', v)

firstname => John
lastname => Smith
age => 27
```

I understand the 2nd loop syntax and how it works, but the 1st one is confusing for me.  Dictionaries have  key/value pairs but it looks like the top one is only looping through the keys, how does it output the values?  Just looking at it I'd expect it to print:

```
firstname => firstname
lastname => lastname
age => age
```

But clearly it doesn't

Comment: This is just how iteration over a dict is defined: it iterates over the keys. Also users[k] gets a value from the dict, why would you expect it to return a key?

Comment: how does it output the values? it looks up the value with the key: `users[k]`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  This is basic access of dict contents, included in myriad tutorials on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python whenever you feed a key to a dictionary it outputs whatever its mapped to aka the value. So :

```
users = {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith', 'age': 27}

>>>firstname #user input
>>>'John' #python output
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

## First loop

In the first loop you are really iterating through keys of your dict.

## Second loop syntax

In python you can assign to tuples:

```
>>> (a, b) = (1, 2)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

So it's the same as doing:

```
>>> xs = (1, 2)
>>> a = xs[0]
>>> b = xs[1]
```

The for loop can be rewritten as:

```
for kv in users.items(): 
  k, v = kv
  # k = kv[0]
  # v = kv[1]
  print(k, '=>', v)
```